# Print one character from string

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management, io

I'm facing an issue connected with printing one char from string in c.
The function takes from users two variables - number (number which should print character from string) and string. When I put as a string "Martin" and number is 5 then the output is "i". But when the number is larger than the string length something goes wrong and I actually don't know what's wrong.

PS. If the number is longer than string size it should print "Nothing".

```
void printLetter() {

    char * string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    int n;

    printf("Number:\n");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    printf("String:\n");
    scanf("%s", string);

    if(n > strlen(string)) {
        printf("nothing");
    } else {
        printf("%c\n", string[n+1]);
    }

    free(string);


}
```

Comment: `char * string = malloc(sizeof(char));` you are allocating space for a single `char` - so if you try to write more than that (in `scanf("%s", string);`) you already get *undefined behavior*

Comment: So i should allocate it like that: `char * string = malloc(100* sizeof(char));` ?

Comment: @UnholySheep how about `scanf("%0s", string);` or `scanf("%*s", string);` that would be safe if `string[0]='\0';` is called first :)

Comment: Yes, you need to allocate more - 100 should be enough. Also note that in this particular code you don't actually need to use `malloc` and `free`, you could just declare a `char` array (e.g.: `char string[100];`)

Comment: string[n+1]-->string[n-1]...also you have allocated only 1 byte for string variable.

Comment: Yeah Vidor you've saved me.

Comment: You may not know the dangers of `scanf`. If you don't, I suggest you read this: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Yea, but I do it only for exams. I do not plan to be C programmer.

Comment: Don't you want n-1? It is zero based index. So position 5 is actually index 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for dynamic allocation here, since you do not know the length of the string in advance, so just do:

```
void printLetter() {
    char string[100]; // example size 100
    ...
    scanf("%99s", string); // read no more than your array can hold
}
```

A fun exercise would be to count the length of the string, allocate dynamically exactly as mush space as you need (+1 for the null terminator), copy `string` to that dynamically allocated space, use it as you wish, and then free it.

---

Moreover this:

```
printf("%c\n", string[n+1]);
```

should be written as this:

```
printf("%c\n", string[n-1]);
```

since you do not want to go out bounds of your array (and cause *Undefined Behavior*), or print two characters next of the requested character, since when I ask for the 1st character, you should print `string[0]`, when I ask for the 2nd, you should print `string[1]`, and so on. So you see why we need to print `string[n-1]`, when the user asks for the `n`-th letter.

By the way, it's common to use a variable named `i`, and not `n` as in your case, when dealing with an *i*ndex. ;)

---

In your code, this:

```
char * string = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

allocates memory for *just one character*, which is no good, since even if the string had one letter only, where would you put the null terminator? You know that strings in C should (almost) always be `NULL` terminated.

In order to allocate dynamically memory for a string of size `N`, you should do:

```
char * string = malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

where you allocate space for `N` characters, plus 1 for the `NULL` terminator.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I was just about to update with exactly what you did, you are an angel.

Comment: @gsamaras Better :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems...

sizeof(char) is generally 1 byte.  Hence malloc() is allocating only one byte of memory to string.  Perhaps a larger block of memory is required?  "Martin", for example, will require at least 6 bytes, plus the string termination character (seven bytes total).

printf("%c\n", string[n+1]) is perhaps not quite right...

```
  String: Martin\0
  strlen= 6
  Offset: 0123456
  n = 5... [n+1] = 6
  The character being output is the string terminator '\0' at index 6.
```

This might work better:

```
  void printLetter() {

      char * string = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
      int n;

      printf("Number:\n");
      scanf("%i", &n);
      printf("String:\n");
      scanf("%s", string);

      if(n > strlen(string)) {
          printf("nothing");
      } else {
          printf("%c\n", string[n-1]);
      }

   free(string);


  }
```

Comment: Why using malloc if you can just declare char string[100]; ?
What will happen when string is more than 100 characters long?

Comment: @DevilaN, There are many things I would do to bring this code up to my standards.  Unfortunately, by then, there would be little resemblance to the question code.  I think it is best to make minimal changes, sufficient to get the code operational without getting into the problems of scant(), buffer sizes, etc.

Comment: Detail: "sizeof(char) is generally 1 byte."  In C, it is always 1 byte, as C defined a _byte_

Answer (score -1):

You are facing buffer overflow.
Take a look to this question, so it will show you how to manage your memory properly in such situation: [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Alternatively you can ask for number of letter and allocate only that much memory + 1. Then `fgets(string, n,stdin);` because you don't need rest of the string :-)